# How to add input widgets to a QTreeWidget in Qt Designer directly?

Tags: qt5, qt-designer, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am writing a program with many parameters that I would like to group together in a single `QTreeWidget` with several columns, the first for parameter name and the others for values like so:

[image]

My problem is that all the solutions I found involve some coding, and it would be much simpler to add elements to the tree directly in Qt Designer. The main reasoning behind that is because my program must not contain any creation of ui element for readability concerns, the ui is imported from a file automatically generated.

Why are `QTreeWidget` hard to manipulate, as opposed to `groupBox` where you can just drag and drop elements?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It wouldn't sense for Qt Designer to try to support every possible feature, so it just does the most common things. If you want additional features, you can write a [custom widget plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Comment: Are you saying that your contents are "static"? Then use a QTreeWidget, not a QTreeView. QTreeWidget is editable directly into Designer, and you can fill it in straight away.

Comment: Hmm I just realized I used both words, when all should be `QTreeWidget`. That is what I am using now and there is no way to fill it with inputs like say a spinbox. All it accepts when adding new elements is text as shown in the picture above. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: And yes those items will be static. For me the tree is just a neater way to group many inputs together.

Comment: So just use a QTreeWidget? You can edit the contents in Designer.

Comment: How? It doesn't let me add widgets in it, just "new elements" which are text as shown in the original post. My current solution, which I wanted to avoid, is to have a wall of text where I define things by hand [like that](https://i.imgur.com/4cKFC12.png).

Comment: @peppe You can edit the content but all content is text instead of input widgets.

Comment: Oh, I see now! So in the screenshot above when you say "combo box" you'd like to have a combobox appear there?

Comment: @peppe Exactly, and it's doable programmatically but that's not as handy.